# Mass and Period in circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Alright. I'm feeling a bit mindblown by the equations for horizontal circular motion, specifically with a pendulum kind of situation.

So we know that with conical horizontal circular motion, the horizontal component of tension is the centripetal force, where values like speed, mass, radius and force all depend on each other:
$$F_T \sin \theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
where $\theta$ is measured from the top. With the knowledge that $F_T \cos\theta = mg$, you can combine these equations to yield
$$\tan \theta=\frac{v^2}{gr}$$
which you can substitute $v=\frac{2\pi r}{T}$ to get
$$T=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2r}{g\tan\theta}}$$

So the only two things that affect the period of motion would be the radius and the angle? I know they all got substituted in/canceled out, but shouldn't mass and velocity play a role as well?

If I had a tennis ball and spun it at a certain angle and radius, and then replaced it with a 300kg ball, would they really have the exact same period and the exact same speed? Shouldn't the heavier ball move somewhat slower? What's going on here?

Comment: *Why* should the heavier ball move slower? You don't present any reasoning for that.

Comment: It may seem *intuitive* for you to assume that a heavier ball would move slower but the math doesn't lie: the period is mass-invariant.

Comment: Your intuition might be influenced by the mass-spring-system. There a larger mass does lead to a lower frequency. In the system considered here however, the effective spring (the gravitational pull towards the center) is also mass dependent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the same reason that (ignoring air resistance) all masses fall at the same speed.

From Newton's second law we get an expression for the acceleration of an object of mass $m$ subjected to a force $F$:

$$ a = \frac{F}{m} $$

The gravitational force on our mass $m$ is given by Newton's law of gravity:

$$ F = \frac{GM_\text{Earth}}{r_\text{Earth}^2}\,m = g\,m $$

And combining these gives the acceleration:

$$ a = \frac{gm}{m} = g $$

So regardless of the mass the acceleration has the same value of $GM/r^2$, which is the well known gravitational acceleration of about $9.81$ m/s$^2$. This means the motion of the object under gravity is independent of the mass, as (allegedly) proved by Galileo some 430 years ago [and by Brian Cox rather more recently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43-CfukEgs).

Exactly the same reasoning applies to your conical pendulum. The force on the bob is proportional to $m$, but the acceleration is proportional to $1/m$. The $m$s cancel out so the centripetal acceleration is independent of the mass of the bob and the motion is the same for all masses.